# How to connect to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, shell

I want to connect to mongodb on some machine through shell script on another Linux machine.
I have used db = connect("192.168.179.130:27017/mydb") command in my shell script but getting an error like Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Please let me know is whether its the right way to do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what programming language do you want to connect? Are you typing this directly into a terminal (shell)? If so, then you should first start the mongo shell. See here: https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/client/

Comment: You will probably need "mongo --host 192.168.179.130 --port 27017 mydb". Also make sure that the mongodb instance is listening on that address. The default is to listen on the loopback interface. More info: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/

Comment: getting error like mongo: not found and use: not found when I run the shell script

Answer (score 0):

mongo admin

The above command will connect the mongo shell to the admin database on the local machine. You may specify a remote database instance, with the resolvable hostname or IP address. Separate the database name from the hostname using a / character. See the following examples:

mongo mongodb1.example.net

mongo mongodb1/admin

mongo 10.8.8.10/test

This syntax is the only way to connect to a specific database.

To specify alternate hosts and a database, you must use this syntax

Comment: I used mongo 192.168.179.132:27017/mydb in my script t.sh but when I run get it I am getting an error like, t.sh: mongo: not found .Do I need to install any API's ?

Comment: You need to add the path to "mongo" to your terminal shell.

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin
Try this

Comment: Still its throwing same error. should I need to install anything else apart from installing mongodb package for Ubuntu?

Comment: delet file in /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock then sudo service mongodb start then mongo It will work

Comment: If I need to to import a json file after connection via mongo command, it takes me to interactive screen rather than importing data through the script.Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Save your connection statements in a seperate `.js` file with following line:

```
db = connect("192.168.179.130:27017/myDatabase");
//do whatever u want like find,update,remove etc
//e.g. db.mycollection.find()
```

e.g. you saved above line in `con.js`, then use command from shell with respective path as:

```
// you need to give full path of `con.js` file

mongo < con.js
```

Comment: Cant we do it through shell script?

Comment: You can call this script in your shell script. For more info please refer [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

Comment: After connecting if I need to load a json file into DB (connected) ,how to do? mongo import is not working